# Why does subtracting one part of a DataFrame column from another part of the same column return an NaN series of the length of the original column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Code used to reproduce the result below, the pandas version used is 1.4.2 in Python 3.9

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'half': ['first half', 'first half', 'second half', 'second half'],
            'vals': [10, 10, 5, 5]
        }
    )
    first_half_s = df.loc[df['half'] == 'first half']['vals']
    second_half_s = df.loc[df['half'] == 'second half']['vals']

    diff_s = first_half_s - second_half_s

>>> diff_s = {Series: (4,)}(0, nan)(1, nan)(2, nan)(3, nan)
```

NB: I managed to do this by turning the series into np arrays and then doing element wise subtraction, but I am trying to figure out why this is happening in Pandas rather then finding a way to do the calculation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is different indices, so subtraction return `NaN`s.

Solution is convert second or first Series to numpy array:

```
first_half_s = df.loc[df['half'] == 'first half','vals']
second_half_s = df.loc[df['half'] == 'second half','vals']


print (first_half_s)
0    10
1    10
Name: vals, dtype: int64

print (second_half_s)
2    5
3    5
Name: vals, dtype: int64

diff_s = first_half_s - second_half_s.to_numpy()
print (diff_s)
0    5
1    5
Name: vals, dtype: int64
```

If set same default indices in both working solution like expecting:

```
#general solution
diff_s = first_half_s.reset_index(drop=True) - second_half_s.reset_index(drop=True)

#solution for this sameple data
#diff_s = first_half_s - second_half_s.reset_index(drop=True)

print (diff_s)
0    5
1    5
Name: vals, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Interesting! I did not know that pandas uses the index to subtract elements in case of equal length series but I guess it makes sense to make things work for any series. Thanks for sharing.